# How do i use LIKE operator in MariaDB for a list of PostalCode with s max and min of 4 characters?

Tags: mysql, database, max, sql-like, min

I have this database with some random information. In the database I need to use the LIKE operator to find all PostalCodes with a minimal of 4 characters and a maximum of 4 characters.

Comment: use four underscore wildcard characters, `postalcode LIKE '____'`   (with the LIKE comparison, the underscore is a wildcard that matches one character (any character, including space, special characters, etc.)

Comment: what is the datatype of column `PostalCodes`?

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks for the answer this seems to be the right answer. I had almost the same but I used a % on the end which let it show everything.

Comment: But `WHERE LENGTH(PostalCode) = 4` is the more obvious way. Why do you *need* to do use the `LIKE` operator?

Comment: The result can be achieved without using the `LIKE` operator;  we could use `CHAR_LENGTH` function to get a count of characters (note that the LENGTH function returns a count of bytes, not characters)  `CHAR_LENGTH(PostalCode)`. We could also use a `REGEXP` comparison operator, one option would be `PostalCode REGEXP '^....$'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `PostalCode` columns is VARCHAR datatype, there are several possible patterns. Using a `LIKE` comparison operator, we could use four underscore wild card characters

```
 PostalCode LIKE '____'
```

Each underscore matches exactly one any character, including space and special characters. Any value of `PostalCode` that has this expression evaluate to 1 (TRUE), we could say it satisfies "max and min of 4 characters".

Another option would be to get a count of the number of characters, using the MySQL `CHAR_LENGTH` function

```
CHAR_LENGTH(PostalCode) = 4
```

In keeping with the requirement to use a `LIKE` operator, we can use LIKE in place of the equals and allow implicit type casting, e.g.

```
CHAR_LENGTH(PostalCode) LIKE '4'
```

Another option would be use REGEXP comparison, for example

```
PostalCode REGEXP '^....$'
```

Again, keeping with the requirement to incorporate a LIKE comparison, we could compare the return from that expression, which is unnecessary obfuscation

```
 ( PostalCode REGEXP '^....$' ) LIKE '1'
```